# Reading a CSV file from media library through power shell script

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

This is working fine

```
$global:ProductPath = "/sitecore/content/Home/Content_Pages/ "
$csv = Import-CSV "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysample\Book1.csv"
$bulk = New-Object "Sitecore.Data.BulkUpdateContext"
try 
{
}
```

but if I direct it to media library like this

```
$csv = "/sitecore/media library/Documents/Book1.csv"
```

or

```
$csv = "/sitecore/media library/Documents/Book1"
```

It is not reading the records from the file.

What should I add, to make my script reading the content from media library folder?

Answer (score 5):

```powershell
# get media item
$media = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/media library/Default Website/FL_insurance_sample"
# get stream and save content to variable $content
[System.IO.Stream]$body = $media.Fields["Blob"].GetBlobStream()
try    
{
    $contents = New-Object byte[] $body.Length
    $body.Read($contents, 0, $body.Length) | Out-Null
} 
finally 
{
    $body.Close()    
}

# convert to dynamic object
$csv = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString($contents) | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ","
$csv
```

source: [Sitecore Content Import with Powershell](https://gist.github.com/pveller/e6a43a9fb9da841fb7c3)